# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unsupported type in filter

Tags: django, mongodb, python-3.6, pymongo

I am working on Project Django with MongoDB (djongo) and I am using mongo atlas But when I am running this command

```
 python3 manage.py runserver 
 python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

this show this type error

```
 pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unsupported type in filter
```

But if I use my local mongod then it's works fine.
Please help me

My requirements.txt

```
    dataclasses==0.6
    dj-database-url==0.5.0
    Django==2.2
    django-cors-headers==3.0.1
    djangorestframework==3.9.4
    djongo==1.2.32
    dnspython==1.16.0
    pymongo==3.8.0
    sqlparse==0.2.4
```

My Db Setting.py

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'leverrage',
            'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://xxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@cluster0-dqfd1.mongodb.net/test?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE&retryWrites=true',
            'USERNAME': 'xxxxxxx',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True,
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Djongo currently is using a deprecated method from pymongo. So I decided to change my pymongo version to the 3.5.1 while djongo fix it.

Answer (score 0):

@Luis Javier Palacio

How did you change the pymongo version?

PD: Can't comment on your answer because of reputation. Thats why I'm "answering" the question.

Answer (score -1):

@Joaquín Gumucio
You can do it using pip like: pip install pymongo==3.5.1

Comment: Do you mean that, downgrading his version of pymongo can get it working ? Or are you assuming pymongo is not installed ? It cannot be the latter as the error is thrown from Pymongo!

Comment: No, it's an answer for @Joaquín Gumucio who asked: "How did you change the pymongo version?"
I couldn't comment on his answer because of reputation. But if you want to solve this issue, if you download pymongo 3.5.1 instead 3.8.0, It might work.