# Mongodb error in Django using Djongo : pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unsupported type in filter

Tags: django, python-3.x, pymongo-3.x, djongo

I am trying to connect a Django project to a MongoDB cluster and when running:

```
py manage.py runserver
```

or

```
py manange.py migrate
```

It keeps showing the same error :

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\introspection.py", line 48, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\introspection.py", line 43, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\introspection.py", line 46, in get_table_list
    for c in cursor.db_conn.collection_names(False)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 715, in collection_names
    nameOnly=True, **kws)]
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 677, in list_collections
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 631, in _list_collections
    session=tmp_session)["cursor"]
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 514, in _command
    client=self.__client)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 579, in command
    unacknowledged=unacknowledged)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 150, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "C:\Users\marlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unsupported type in filter
```

My setting.py configuration is:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'djongo',
    'NAME': 'database_django',
    'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://xxxxxx:aaaaaa@isssgeneral-sfm0v.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    'PORT': 27017,
    'USERNAME': 'xxxxxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'aaaaaa' 
}
}
```

My python environment is the following:

```
pymongo            3.7.0
Django             2.2.2 
djongo             1.2.32
sqlparse           0.2.4
dnspython          1.16.0
```

I already tried with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56280057/pymongo-errors-operationfailure-unsupported-type-in-filter) solution that suggests to downgrade the pymongo to 3.5.1 version, which already tried but did not worked. In fact, the project worked previously in the pymongo==3.7 version (the one I have in the envionment at the moment).

I have configured this Django project to connect to the local server and it works, apparently there is something about the host name that does not fit. There is no problem with cluster configuration (I think), since I have a Jupyter Notebook that connects directly to the same cluster.

Really does not know what happened to my project that suddenly stopped connecting to my Mongodb cluster. Could anyone assist me to find the solution for this problem?

Thank you community.

Comment: EDIT: solved the issue by installing Deepin (Does not matter the distro, I am just stating that I switched from Windows to a Linux environment) and installed all python and Mongo tools to work with my project. Then I deployed the project into Heroku as a Heroku app and It works perfectly in my laptop and in Heroku's environment.